# why authentication-failure-url in spring security not working

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am using spring security in my website, but when I used custom login form (`JSF` form), and user entered bad credentials, `authentication-failure-url` is not working and user is not forwarded to `failed.xhtml`, but `index.xhtml` is appeared

I don't know the reason, please help:

applicationContext.xml:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.1.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myspring" />
    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- beans configuration -->
    <beans:bean id="userBo" class="com.myspring.user.bo.impl.UserBoImpl" />



    <!-- security configuration -->
    <http auto-config="true">

        <intercept-url pattern="/login.xhtml" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/index.xhtml" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/authenticated.xhtml" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/views/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />

        <form-login login-page="/login.xhtml" default-target-url="/authenticated.xhtml"
            authentication-failure-url="/failed.xhtml" />
        <logout invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="true" logout-success-url="/"/>
        <csrf disabled="true" />
    </http>
    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="user1" password="user1Pass" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

login.xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <div style="">
        <h:form id="loginFormId" prependId="false">
            <div id="loginFieldsPnlId">
                <div id="loginFieldUsrContId">
                    <h:outputText id="outTxtUserNameId" value="Username: "
                        name="outTxtUserNameNm"></h:outputText>
                    <h:inputText id="userName" required="true"
                        value="#{loginController.userName}"
                        requiredMessage="Please enter username"></h:inputText>
                    <h:outputLabel id="outLblUserNameId" for="userName"
                        name="outLblUserNameNm"></h:outputLabel>
                </div>
                <div id="loginFieldPassContId">
                    <h:outputText id="outTxtPasswordId" value="Password: "
                        name="outTxtPasswordNm"></h:outputText>
                    <h:inputSecret id="password" required="true"
                        value="#{loginController.password}"
                        requiredMessage="Please enter password" name="inTxtPasswordNm"></h:inputSecret>
                    <h:outputLabel id="outLblPasswordId" for="password"
                        name="outLblPasswordNm"></h:outputLabel>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="loginBtnPanelId">
                <h:commandButton id="btnLoginId" value="Login"
                    action="#{loginController.login}" styleClass="loginPanelBtn"></h:commandButton>
                <h:commandButton id="btnCancelId" value="Cancel"
                    action="#{loginController.cancel}" styleClass="loginPanelBtn"
                    immediate="true" update="loginFormId"></h:commandButton>
            </div>
        </h:form>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h:messages></h:messages>
    </div>
</h:body>
</html>
```

and this is the loginController with login method:

```
package com.myspring.controllers;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;


@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class LoginController {


    private String userName;

    private String password;


    @ManagedProperty(value="#{authenticationManager}")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager = null;

    public String login() {
        try {
            Authentication request = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(this.getUserName(), this.getPassword());
            Authentication result = authenticationManager.authenticate(request);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(result);
        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "failed";
        }
        return "success";
    }

    public String logout(){
        SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
        return "loggedout";
    }

    public AuthenticationManager getAuthenticationManager() {
        return authenticationManager;
    }

    public void setAuthenticationManager(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    public String cancel()
    {
        return "";
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }


    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }


    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }


}
```

also I will add project structure:

[image]

Comment: It isn't working because Spring security isn't in control, you are replacing the functionality of the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` with your JSF backing bean. So basically all properties after setting the login.xhtml are pretty much useless.

Comment: can you tell me how to use `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` with JSF

Comment: Don't use JSF. Only add the login.xhtml but with a plain form, which is then submitted to `/login` (which is handled by Spring Security). You can still use facelets but don't use a JSF backing bean just a plain form submit. The same applies for the logout, don't use a backing bean just a link to `/logout` or if you use the CSFR protection a form that posts to `/logout`.

Comment: @M.Deinum can you update the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the fact that you are using JSF you are basically bypassing the login (and logout) functionality provided by Spring Security. Your `LoginController` is basically replacing that, due to that your `sec:login-form` and `sec:legato` are pretty much useless.

The solution is simple don't use JSF, you can still use Facelets to render your page, but simply include a normal `form` tag which posts to `/login` instead of an `h:form` tag and you can remove your `LoginController`.

**Note:** If your application is *not* the root application (i.e. mapped to `/`) you need to include the `/context-path` into your URL. So instead of `/login` use `/context-path/login`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <div style="">
        <form id="loginFormId" method="post" action="/login">
            <div id="loginFieldsPnlId">
                <div id="loginFieldUsrContId">
                    <label>Username:<label>
                    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" />
                </div>
                <div id="loginFieldPassContId">
                    <label>Password:<label>
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="loginBtnPanelId">
                <button>Login</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</h:body>
</html>
```

If you still want to use JSF and the `LoginController` then don't directly use the `AuthenticationManager` but forward the request to the `/login` URL that way Spring Security will take over after JSF has done the required validation.

Comment: use same applicationContext?

Comment: Yes that doesn't change else I would have put that in the answer

Comment: I used your html form, after login it forwarded me to this url `http://localhost:8080/login`

Comment: Which would be correct if that is the URL you entered to access the application. It will redirect you, by default, to the URL you requested. I assume here that that is a successful login.

Comment: I put /{application name}/login, and it works fine, what about logout?